# How to apply a fitted Tree-augmented Naive Bayes classifier to new cases

Tags: conditional-probability, naive-bayes, bayesian-network

I am running Tree Augmented Naive Bayes algorithm in R and I have got the desired network. However, unlike logistic regression, Bayesian is non-parametric i.e. I do not have any coefficients which I can save and use to calculate fresh scores. I wanted to understand ways to implement the Bayesian output in SQL frame i.e. how can I automate it in SQL so that for every round of fresh data, I run the trained network to predict the probability score.

I am trying to use the conditional probability tables from bn.fit and back calculate the predicted probabilities using conditional independence and Bayes theorm. But my results are not matching with R's predicted probabilities output.

Comment: This is going to be hard to answer. It isn't clear if you need code review (which would go on the [codereview.SE] SE site, BTW, not here), but there isn't any code to review. You also might be asking for SQL code (which would also be off topic here--it could go on [SO] if you had a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)). Can you clarify your question & especially its *statistical* aspects?

Answer (score 2):

> However, unlike logistic regression, Bayesian is non-parametric i.e. I do not have any coefficients which I can save and use to calculate fresh scores.

Nope.  It's certainly not a non-parametric model.  Maybe look up the definition of the model to confirm.

> I wanted to understand ways to implement the Bayesian output in SQL frame i.e. how can I automate it in SQL so that for every round of fresh data, I run the trained network to predict the probability score.

Right - you want to implement model prediction in your own code after the R has estimated the network parameters.

> I am trying to use the conditional probability tables from bn.fit

so you're using the package [bnlearn](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/bnlearn/index.html).

> and back calculate the predicted probabilities using conditional independence and Bayes theorm. But my results are not matching with R's predicted probabilities output.

Indeed.  If you looked up the definition of the model earlier you'll notice that while in regular Naive Bayes the observations are conditionally independent given the class, in tree-augmented NB they are *not* (modeling these dependencies is the augmentation).  Hence you'll need to compute the posterior probability of the class taking into account that extra bit of conditioning.

It's possible that you can look in the tree.bn specific version of `predict` to see how the package does already it.  Alternatively you can just write down the prior and likelihood in the model and figure out what the posterior would be.  It's not much harder than deriving that for the unaugmented NB, particularly as you only need it up to a proportionality.

If you end up writing it yourself you'll want to think carefully about overflow issues - particularly with a lot of features - but any machine learning text should explain how to deal with those in a NB context.